# How to build an pipeline jobs in parallel based on choice parameters values?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins, right now i am configuring the pipeline job that can run based on choice parameters values, for each choice values there is an certain jobs need to run in parallel. for example here i need to build Job1 parameter then its only need to build Job1's parallel jobs. but i tried it here its building all the jobs, is there an way to build the jobs based on parameter values?

```
Choice Parameter
Name: Param
Value:  Job1
        Job2

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
node('') {
String 
stage ('Parallel-Job1'){
parallel(Job1: {
    stage ('Parallel-test1'){
    build job: 'test1', propagate: false
    def jobname1 = "test1"
    }
}, Job1: {
    stage ('Parallel-test2'){
    build job: 'test2', propagate: false
    def jobname2 = "test2"
    }
})
stage ('Parallel-Job2'){
parallel(Job2: {
    stage ('Parallel-test3'){
    build job: 'test3', propagate: false
    def jobname1 = "test3"
    }
})
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (param == "Job1") {
    stage('Parallel-Job1') {steps ..}
```

PA: in this case you won't see the skipped pipeline stage on the general view

Or:

```
stage('conditional stage') {
agent label:'my-node'
when {
expression {
    return ${Param} != 'Job1';
    }
}
steps {
    echo 'foo bar'
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @yarin , I tried this if condition but its not even passing in the pipeline.